# How to replace matched string php

Tags: php, regex

I have string like following format:

```
$string ='[(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)name|name]
  [(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)]
  [(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)name|name]
  [(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)]
  [(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)name]';
```

if part of the string does not contain `name`, remove that part from the string.

so output will be like

```
$output ='[(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)name|name]
   [(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)name|name]
   [(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)name]';
```

I have tried something like this

```
 $re = '/\[\((.*?)\)(.*?)\]/s';
```

but not working as expected

Comment: can u minimize example i read it 5x times and scroll both lines and still dont undestand what u want to do

Comment: @ImreRaudsepp. i have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find each string, which:

- starts with optional "white" characters,
- then contains `[` and `(`.
- then a sequence of chars other than `)` (the content between parentheses),
- then `)` and `]` without any chars between them (names)

and replace it with an empty string.

So the regex should be: `\s*\[\([^)]+\)\]`.

Note that `\n` is also a white char, so actually there is deleted:

- the newline preceding the text without names (if any),
- and the row in question (including starting spaces, if any),

but the newline terminating this row (if any) is not deleted.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/NVGild/1

Answer (score 0):

```
$string ='[(id,name,top,left,width,height,dePPpth)name|name][(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)][(id,name,top,left,width,height,dePPPpth)name|name][(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)][(id,name,top,left,width,height,deppth)name]';
preg_match_all('/(\[\([a-zA-Z,]+\)name(\|name)?\])/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

and then implode matches